# Group concatinate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, group-concat

I'm trying to group concatenate my role names

```
select 
    FirstName, 
    (
        select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct role.Name SEPARATOR ', ')
        from user_roles r 
        inner join users u ON u.Id = r.Userid 
        inner join roles role ON r.RoleId = role.Id
        where role.Active = 1 and role.IsDeleted = 0 and r.UserId = u.Id
    ) As rloleList 
from users;
```

I'm getting the same role names for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select 
    u.firstname, 
    group_concat(distinct r.name separator ', ') rolelist 
from user_roles ur 
inner join users u on u.id = ur.userid 
inner join roles r on r.id  = ur.roleid
where r.active = 1 and r.isdeleted = 0
group by u.id, u.firstname
```

I am unusure that you do need `distinct` in `group_concat()`; it there are no duplicate roles for a given user (as it should be, given your schema), then just remove it to make the query more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to group concatenate my role names

The basic idea is:

```
select u.UserId, u.firstname,
       group_concat(role_name separateor ', ') as roles
from user_roles ur inner join
     users u 
     on u.Id = ur.Userid inner join
     roles r 
     on r.RoleId = ur.Id
group by u.UserId, u.firstname;
```

In most databases, `user_roles` would not have duplicates, so there is no need for `distinct` in `group_concat()`.  If duplicates are possible, then include it.

Your query has additional filtering which you do not explain so I have not included them.  You can just add the `where` clause:

```
where r.Active = 1 and r.IsDeleted = 0
```

if these additional conditions are required.